# Change references and bibliography in MS Word in ISO690

Tags: xslt, reference, cpu-word

I would need to change references brackets in MS Word from this one ( ) to this one [ ], additionaly I need to set number between them to be blue. In bibliography I need to make it look like list starting with numbers in brackets, for example: [1] Special relativity. This number can't be blue. When I create reference to equation it has to be blue but in ( ) brackets.

I have tried this one: https://superuser.com/questions/1074258/ms-word-2016-square-brackets-in-reference-list-iso-690/1212127 ; but there is no word about coloring.

Link to my current style: https://uloz.to/tamhle/AufCak9pbJqT#!ZJZ4LwR2AwOvMQx5ZQAxBTDmZmH5ZSEkFzW0HyV4qx9sJQIuBD==

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Please show us your source xml, the wanted outcome en the xsl you have tried so far.

Comment: I have added the custom style which I made.